# Why does JobExecutionDecider have a stepExecution provided to the decide method?

Tags: spring-batch

In my experience this stepExecution is always null when decider is invoked.  It seems like a JobExecutionDecider is tied to a job execution which is provided to the decide method, but since a job decider isn't tied to any single step there is no step execution to provide.

Is there something I'm missing?  Is there another way to use a JobExecutionDecider where stepExecution will not be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why `stepExecution` is always `null` in your case as you have not posted your configuration and your question is not a bit clear either.

Having said that , refer to the scenario illustrated in [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#programmaticFlowDecisions), there it is explained in configuration that if execution goes to `step2` or `step3`  depends on `someCondition`.

That `someCondition` might further be dependent on `step1` execution i.e. you might be using this step1 - stepExecution to make `someCondition` `true` or `false`.

That is totally up to you as what that condition might be and what it might use but as per that illustration, stepExecution will not be null since that evaluation happens after step1 has stopped executing and its execution is available.

Also, quote ,

> In some situations, more information than the ExitStatus may be
>   required to decide which step to execute next

Which means that by default framework already uses this kind of a decider which is based on only step's `ExitStatus` . You can override that logic here to use additional columns in making that decision.

Also, quoting [API docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html),

> Strategy for branching an execution based on the state of an ongoing
>   JobExecution. The return value will be used as a status to determine
>   the next step in the job.

Ongoing `JobExceution` is a master container that includes stepexecutions too.

Also, as per JavaDoc at source , `@param stepExecution the latest step execution (may be null)`

Hope it helps !!

Comment: The JavaDoc was what I was missing (this details about "the latest step execution (may be null)" is missing in the spring batch docs that discuss decider, here is a link to the javadoc you mention http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/job/flow/JobExecutionDecider.html

Comment: glad to of help !!

Answer (score 1):

Even I have seen the same thing in my code. but what I guess if you are using decider step as the very first step of the job it will come as null and if you use decider step as any further step instead of first step it will not be null. because i think spring uses `StepExecution` as the medium to communicate data between the various steps of the job.